# Unable to get the length of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

I am using an array as defined below

`cat_id = Object { 2="text", 3="TKL1", -1="Select an Attribute"}`.

when i am trying to retrieve the length of `"cat_id"` as
`var l = cat_id.length;`
its showing the length as `"undefined"`.
But, I am unable to get the length of `"cat_id"`. I am unable to use `replace()`, `indexOf()` and `split()` functions.

for example:

```
var index = cat_attr.indexOf(",")
```

Its showing error as below:

> TypeError: cat_attr.indexOf is not a function

Comment: You seem to be confused about what an array is. In JavaScript, as well as most other non-PHP languages, `[1, 2, 3]` is an array. `{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }` is called *object* in JavaScript, or dictionary (Python) or a hashtable (Java) or just semiincorectly a hash (Ruby). A JS object does not have a length, but you can extract an array of its keys, which does.

Comment: this is not an array. try this instead of your code   var cat_id = [ '2="text"', '3="TKL1"', '-1="Select an Attribute"']; 

var len=cat_id.length;
alert(len);

Answer (score 2):

This isn't array, this is Object. Array defined in this way: `[1,2,3]`. If you want retrieve the "length" of object you can do this in this way:

```
var students = {job:92, adam:67,sara:83};
var studentNames = Object.keys(students);
var studentsLength = studentNames.length;
```

If you want split object to array you can do this in this way:

```
var students = {jon:92, adam:67,sara:83};
var studentNames = Object.keys(students);
var studentArray = studentNames.map(function(name){
    var student = {};
    student.name = name;
    student.grade = students[name];
    return (student);
}); // [{name:jon,grade:92},{name:adam,grade:67},{name:sara,grade:83}]
```

Comment: can you provide an example with this ??

Comment: are you sure cat_id = Object { 2="text", 3="TKL1", -1="Select an Attribute"}.  is a valid object in js ??

Comment: This isn't valid object in js. I think he didn't type the object in this way in his code.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I split the elements in an object. Here I cannot use an array.

Comment: I am getting the value of object in cat_id dynamically from another function.

Comment: Here again studentArray is an object. How to convert that to an array. I need to split it.

Comment: This is an array of objects. If you want value array you can do this in this way. `Object.keys(cat_id).map(function(key){return cat_id[key]});`

Answer (score 0):

`cat_id` variable you defined as not an array, it is a javascript object. That is why it is not behaving like array! `[]` is the array notation. Use array notation `[]` instead of `{}` object notation you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is wrong type and wrong syntax.

In your question your cat_id is an Object, not string or array. So you can not call length() or indexOf() funtion.

Moreover, you typed wrong syntax, it should be:

```
var cat_id = { 2: 'text', 3: 'TKL1', -1: 'Select an Attribute'}.
```

Comment: I am using 
var cat_id = { 2: 'text', 3: 'TKL1', -1: 'Select an Attribute'}. 
var attr_name = Object.keys(cat_attr);
in attr_name the values i am getting are:
attr_name =["2", "3", "-1"]
but  i want "text", "tkl1", "select an attribute" in attr_name.
how can i get those values?

Comment: Can you please respond me as soon as possible

Comment: 1. Methods
Object.keys(cat_id).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(cat_id[key]);
 });

2. Or simple:
var a = cat_id[2];
var b = cat_id[3];
var c = cat_id[-1];

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to retrieve property count (size and/or length)

```
size_obj = Object.keys(my_object).length;
```

As in

```
size_cat_id = Object.keys(cat_id).length;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you give an example of how to convert an object to an array or to a string.

Comment: Not sure what you're driving at ... canonical object to string is  var str_value = JSON.stringify(some_object);    object to array is not so generally accepted